# Why referencing in a nested ranged-based for-loops

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a newbie in C++.

1. Why can't we iterate through `int*`?
2. What is the use of `&` here?
3. How does this nested range-based for perform, deeply?

.

```
int arr[10][3];

for (auto &i : arr)
{
    for (auto j : i)
    {
        //sth
    }
}
```

Comment: Why **should** we iterate through `int*`? Other than that, looks like a dupe.

Comment: http://ideone.com/CzP07k for a http://sscce.org

Comment: `int*` is not a container. You can't iterate "through" it. Instead, it _is_ an iterator.

Comment: Question this was marked as a duplicate does not answer every part of this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, we need to know the exact data type of `int arr[10][3];`. It is an *array of 10 arrays of 3 `int`*.

A loop typically iterates over one dimension of a multidimensional container, e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        arr[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

The first loop iterates over the *array of 10 `X`*, the second loop then iterates over `X`, which here is an *array of 3 `int`*.

The next step is to explicitly use this `X` in code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int (&x)[3] = arr[i];  // you won't see this syntax often

    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        int &elem = x[j];
        elem = 0;
    }
}
```

The line `int (&x)[3]` declares a reference to an *array of 3 `int`*, which is the result of accessing the first level of the multidimensional array `arr`.

We can also write this example using iterators:

```
for(int (*px)[3] = arr; px != arr+10; ++px)
{
    // `px` is a _pointer to an array of 3 `int`_
    // `*px` then is an _array of 3 `int`_

    for(int *pelem = *px; pelem != (*px)+3; ++pelem)
    {
        *pelem = 0;
    }
}
```

Note I'm using a feature here that converts an array to a pointer to its first element. This is called *decaying*: an array is/can be decayed to a pointer (to the first element of that array), e.g.

```
int my_arr[3];
int *p = my_arr;  // `p` now points to the first element of `my_arr`
     p = &my_arr[0]; // equivalent
```

For multidimensional arrays, this becomes

```
int arr[10][3];
int (*p)[3];    // a pointer to an _array of 3 `int`_
p = arr;        // `p` now points to the first element of `arr`, i.e.
                // the first _array of 3 `int`_
```

---

Last but not least, for multidimensional arrays, it is also possible to write:

```
for(int *pelem = arr[0]; pelem != arr[0]+10*3; ++pelem)
{
    *pelem = 0;
}
```

But this is only possible for multidimensional arrays, as they're laid out contiguously in memory, and the memory layout of multidimensional arrays is specified.

This is not possible for a container like `vector<vector<int>>`, even though

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
for(int* i = &v[0]; i != &v[0] + 5; ++i)
{
    *i = 0;
}
```

is well-formed and has no undefined behaviour.

---

The same logic now applies to range-based for loops:

```
for(int (&x)[3] : arr)
{
    for(int &elem : x)
    {
        elem = 0;
    }
}
```

The whole point of having range-based for loops is to get rid of explicit iterators. `int*` is such an iterator, so there's no point in having a range-based for loop that iterates over `int*` IMO.

---

> how does this nested range-based for perform, deeply?

The C++ language Standard defines the range-based for statement in [stmt.ranged] as follows (note I've simplified it a bit):

> `for (` *for-range-declaration* `:` *expression* `)` *statement*

is resolved to:

```
{
    for ( auto __begin = /*begin-expr*/,
               __end = /*end-expr*/;
          __begin != __end;
          ++__begin )
    {
        /*for-range-declaration*/ = *__begin;
        /*statement*/
    }
}
```

Where *for-range-declaration* and *statement* are essentially copy-pasted from the unresolved range-based for loop. The rest (*begin-expr*, *end-expr*) has some intricacies, here's a simplified version:

```
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    for ( auto __begin = begin(/*expression*/),
               __end = end(/*expression*/);
          __begin != __end;
          ++__begin )
    {
        /*for-range-declaration*/ = *__begin;
        /*statement*/
    }
}
```

My example of a range-based for loop is resolved from

```
for(int (&x)[3] : arr)
{
    /*statements*/
}
```

to

```
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    for ( auto __begin = begin(arr),
               __end = end(arr);
          __begin != __end;
          ++__begin )
    {
        int (&x)[3] = *__begin;
        /*statements*/
    }
}
```

Or, by resolving the `begin`/`end` calls:

```
{
    for ( int (*__begin)[3] = arr,
               __end = arr + 10;
          __begin != __end;
          ++__begin )
    {
        int (&x)[3] = *__begin;           // (A)
        /*statements*/
    }
}
```

---

The line marked with an `(A)` also shows why the `&` in an example `for (int x[3] : arr)` is necessary:

```
int arr[10][3];
int (&x)[3] = arr[0];   // well-formed
int   x [3] = arr[0];   // ill-formed for arrays
```

It is not allowed to directly assign a raw/C-style array, as you may know from examples like

```
int my_arr[10];
int my_sec_arr[10] = my_arr;  // not legal, ill-formed
```

This is why you have to use a reference.

With other containers like the Standard Library's `std::array`, it is possible to avoid the reference:

```
std::array<int, 10> my_arr;
std::array<int, 10> my_sec_arr = my_arr;  // well-formed
```

But assigning means a copy, so the whole array had to be copied; whereas a reference here doesn't require copying.

---

As [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk) pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907913/why-referencing-in-a-nested-ranged-based-for-loops/17908188#comment26159960_17908188), this isn't quite the reason why the `&` is necessary in *your* example `for (auto &i : arr)`, as `auto &i = arr[0];` is resolved to `int (*i)[3] = arr[0];`. But as you can see, `auto` decays the array into a pointer, so your second iteration fails:

```
for(auto i : arr)
{
    // type of `i` now is _pointer to an array of 3 `int`_
    for(auto j : i) // can't iterate over a pointer: what are the boundaries?
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

To be a bit more precise: you can iterate over an array, as the compiler knows how many elements there are in the array; it's part of the type, e.g. *array of 3 `int`*, and the type is known to the compiler.

For pointers, the compiler doesn't know if the pointer refers to a single element or to an array of elements, and in the latter case it doesn't know how large that array is. The type in any case is just, e.g. *pointer to `int`*:

```
int my_arr[10];
int my_int;

int *p;
p = my_arr;
p = &my_int;
p = new int[25];
```

Comment: There is an implicit, hidden question above: why http://ideone.com/Z1DMwO doesn't work. (my decoding of what "Why can't we iterate through `int*`" means)

Comment: @Yakk hope I just addressed this with my last/latest paragraph

Comment: The assignment doesn't error out, actually.  `auto x = array;` works fine, but the array decays into a pointer, while `auto& x = array` stays as a reference to the array: the error happens when you try to iterate over that pointer.

Comment: @Yakk Huh! You're right. Something I didn't knew about `auto`.

Comment: +1 for a really in depth answer. But, for some reason, I still prefer the simple, straight forward `for(long i = 0; i < count; i++) { ... }` expression. Nothing hidden, no intricacies to be aware of...

Comment: @cmaster For some containers, using iterators is faster than using indices, such as boost matrix on MSVC compilers. You can, however, use something like `for(auto i = begin(cont); i != end(cont); ++i)`, but that has not much less intricacies than the range-based for loop. Btw I'd rather say try to avoid C-style arrays, multidim arrays just emphasize their problems ;)

Comment: @DyP Yes, I avoid anything like `int array[123]` like hell, yet not because it's C-style, but because it's a fixed array size, and my experience tells me, to avoid fixed limits at all costs. There's nothing wrong with a properly managed C-style, dynamically allocated array IMHO, it's not less safe as using a vector, and definitely at least as fast.

Comment: @cmaster Indexes only work for random access containers, which not all containers are.  And yes, C-style arrays are less safe: what happens when someone `return`s in more than one spot, or heaven help you `throw`s?  RAII is a godsend, and `vector` is little more than a `RAII` wrapped C-style buffer with lots of *free* or *cheap* bells and whistles on top.

Comment: @cmaster 'Yakk *and other* lovers of exceptions'?  Repeating '`vector` is little more than a `RAII` wrapped C-stype buffer' as if I did not just write it, but in different words?  Your post implies a complete misreading of mine: because it either repeats mine while implying new content, or strenuously disagrees with a position my post did not contain.  Hence 'you seem to be reading a post I did not write' given your response.  Anyhow, these comments are not useful: barring something useful, I'll be deleting these shortly.

Comment: @cmaster This went slightly overboard. What I meant with "try to avoid C-style arrays" was not safety, but ease-of-use. You can't return or assign them, the syntax for passing them is ugly and not well-known, they decay to pointers too easily; multidim arrays lead to confusion about types, the order of brackets and iteration. There are places where fixed-size arrays are better-suited than dynamically sized ones, but I'd rather use `std::array` in those cases. `vector` vs `new[]` is unrelated to this.